# Choose two groups of 2 from a set of $n$ things

Tags: combinatorics

My solution is to do $\binom{n}{4} \binom{4}{2} / 2$, dividing by two to deal with "complementary" groups. I wonder if theres a better solution?

Comment: Yours has the virtue of reducing at once to $3\binom{n}4$, with a single binomial coefficient involving the parameter $n$; the other natural approach, given by **Valborg**, leaves you with two binomial coefficients involving $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Perahps the most straight forward way of doing this is to litterally choose a group of 2, and then choose another group of 2 (assuming that the two groups must be disjoint), so you get $\frac{1}{2}\cdot{{n}\choose{2}}{{n-2}\choose{2}}$, after accounting for the complementary choices you mentioned earlier.

EDIT: Oops, left that 1/2 out.

Comment: You must also divide by 2, otherwise you're counting every decomposition twice.